# iPhone Emulator/Intepreter for Native Apps (Compiled for ARM)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, emulation, ipod

When working in Xcode, Apple compiles a mobile program for i386 (since the iPhone/iPad/iPod emulators are i386). Code *is not* compiled for ARM then run on a desktop emulator performing interpretation.

I'm interested in an emulator/interpreter/virtual machine that runs real iOS applications (which would have been compiled for ARM). We want to perform malware analysis in a lab-like state.

Does Apple provide such a tool (I have not been able to locate it)? Has anyone come across a ARM-compatible emulator or interpreter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry to disappoint you - the best you can get right now in terms of native ARM emulation specifically for the iPhone mainly boots the kernel.

You can only attach to a shell and recover a ROM from iTunes into the Qemu-provided device AFAICT. The project is called [iEmu](http://www.iemu.org), and is written specifically for i*-devices (iPad, iPhone etc.)

While progress (please look at the "development / status" page on iEmu.org) is rather slow, the project isn't dead.
Any progress beyond that might be observed at the [project's github page (called QEMU-s5l89xx-port)](https://github.com/cmwdotme/QEMU-s5l89xx-port).

Comment: Its been a couple of years... Has anything changed that you are aware of?

Comment: A few more years have passed and things are looking up: https://github.com/alephsecurity/xnu-qemu-arm64